# Обращение к свойствам объекта каскадно, точно не зная какая глубина

Tags: javascript, typescript, объекты, properties

Скажем, есть некий объект:

```
let obj1 = {
  user: {
    name: 'Igor',
    age: 29,
    upics: ['igor29.png', 'igor29.gif']
  },
  books: [14, 88, 20, 19, 170, 3]
};
```

Нужен некий метод, который позволит получить свойства из объекта, имея просто массив ключей. Например:

`let neededProperty = getObjProperty(obj1, ['user','name']);`

Есть ли в Javascript (или, там, в typescript) какая-то готовая конструкция/метод для получения подобных каскадных свойств (причём изначально не зная структуру объекта), или надо реализовывать подобные вещи через частные случаи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовой конструкции нет.

```js
function getObjProperty(obj, props) {
  for (var i = 0; obj && i < props.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[props[i]];
  }
  return obj;
}

let obj1 = {
  user: {
    name: 'Igor',
    age: 29,
    upics: ['igor29.png', 'igor29.gif']
  },
  books: [14, 88, 20, 19, 170, 3]
};

let neededProperty = getObjProperty(obj1, ['user', 'name']);
console.log(neededProperty);
console.log(getObjProperty(obj1, ['user2', 'name']));
console.log(getObjProperty(obj1, ['books', 3]));
console.log(getObjProperty(obj1, ['user', 'upics', 1]));
```